# sed: 1: "./.classpath": invalid command code . error. what's the issue?

Tags: java, regex, git, bash, sed

I get an error as in the picture. I have a file named .classpath. What the root cause?

[image]

```
dbao@bothlower-lm 13:45:34 -/git/profile_load_generator $find . -path ./ .git -prune -o -type f -print0 l xargs -0 sed -i 's/yahoo/zbipp/g' - sed: 1 &quot;-&quot;:./.classpath&quot;: invalid command code.

dbao@bothlower-lm 13:47:16 -/git/profile_load_generator $find . -path ./ .git -prune -o -type f -print0 l xargs -0 sed -i 's/yahoo/zbipp/g' - sed: 1 &quot;-&quot;:./.classpath&quot;: invalid command code.

dbao@bothlower-lm 17:40:16 -/git/profile_load_generator $ ls
```

> bin conf pkg pom.xml src

```
dbao@bothlower-lm 17:40:16 -/git/profile_load_generator $ ls -l ./.classpath
```

> -rw-r--r-- 1 dbao Y\Domain Users 998 Jan 18 17:18 ./.classpath

Answer (score 1):

The `sed`-option `-i` requires an argument in its *BSD-version* (as opposed to the GNU version), which is the extension of a backup file created prior to in-place editing the file. If you do not need this, leave it empty by specifying `-i ""`:

```
find . -path ./ .git -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" 's/yahoo/zbipp/g'
```

The error occurs, because `'s/yahoo/zbipp/g'` was taken as the argument to `-i` and the first char of the first filename was then parsed as command code (which usually is `s`, but was invalid then)

Comment: GNU sed does not require an argument to `-i`, but I'm guessing you're right here, that they're using BSD sed

Comment: @EricRenouf Correct, I added that fact to avoid confusion.